# Track Button Events Pagewise in one page in Asp.Net Application

Tags: asp.net

Need to send mail from each and every aspx page when button is clicked based on some conditions. Instead of writing mail send code in every page(button is clicked), is that possible to track button click events in one place for an application and send mail.

Comment: Write email send method in a public class file and call the same from all the aspx pages

Comment: Instead of modifying in all aspx pages is there any way to track button click events in one page and call send method

Comment: no, you can't do that.

Comment: in global.asax file or in master page file can we able to track button click events occurred page wise..Thanks in advance Sunil

Comment: for every post back in aspx page, global.ascx and master pages events will be fired but you can't track from which control it was been triggered. even tough if you tracked, you can't stop to run the code written in 'onclick' event of button.